# FB share button - not working - Javascript not being called

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I'm trying to get the FB share button to work as explained here http://www.fbrell.com/saved/2779dc018c325d85d650a3b723239650?fbclid=IwAR3TfNb3SqLFGHpp-C7UhKDRT1tbFhsfWi5oV1tbD90mAwIUxKMkSXjsBxk and here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog
but it won't work, nothing happens when clicking on the button. The JS is not being called. Any ideas? Cheers

```
<div id="shareBtn" class="btn btn-success clearfix">Share</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  display: 'popup',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  }, function(response){});
}
</script>
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2hnL5btf/

Comment: The JS is being called in the example link you posted... It certainly works.

Comment: No it's not! https://jsfiddle.net/2hnL5btf/

Comment: Are you even including the FB SDK....? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

Comment: "nothing happens" is not a sufficient description. you would see a very specific error in the browser console that FB is not defined, for example. which means that you did not load the javascript sdk.

Comment: In your fiddle the `<script>` tags are wrong, those don’t belong into the JavaScript input section. And after you corrected that, the browser console will tell you where you messed up next …

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize Facebook SDK:

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'your-app-id',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.2'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```